# Have an HTML - how do i get data from its tables using xpath

Tags: python, xpath

Using selenium to navigate to a page, log in, run a script which populates a search results table. I use this to get the innerHTML code. Now I am trying to use xpath to get the actual data out of the table but am stuck.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import requests

browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
url = "www.url.com"
browser.get(url) 

username = browser.find_element_by_id("username") #username form field
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password") #password form field

username.send_keys("myusername")
password.send_keys("mypassword")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Next I navigate to the page I am interested in and get the innerHTML

```
browser.get('a different url')
innerHTML= browser.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
tree = html.fromstring(innerHTML)
```

There is a table which has

```
<tbody id='searchResultsPage'>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
...
```

So I am trying to cycle through each row and each column to get the text out. I can build a loop to cycle through based on row and column number. So I tried:

```
thisItem = tree.xpath('//tbody[id="searchResultsPage"]/tr[position()=9]/td[position()=3]/text()')
print(thisRow)
```

I get nothing returned.

I also noticed that one of the columns is a bunch of links with class "action view record". So I tried the below:

```
companies = tree.xpath('//a[@class="action-view-record"]/text()')
print(companies)
```

And that works (though doesn't solve my original problem since the remaining columns are just  tags). But for some reason it only works sometimes. about 50% of the times the code returns nothing, the rest of the time it returns the right data (a list of companies).

Any thoughts on how to navigate the table? and why sometimes the code breaks?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this table:

```
<table id='searchResultsPage'>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Extract it with the regex `<table[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/table>\s*`

This way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

htmltable = re.findall(r'<tbody[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/tr>\s*', htmldoc)

table = ET.XML(htmltable[0])
rows = iter(table)
headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]

print headers
```

You will get:

```
['...', '...']
```

Then, depending on the complexity of the table you can do:

```
listtable = []

for row in rows:
    values = [col.text for col in row]
    listtable.append(dict(zip(headers, values)))

return listtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like :

```
table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='table_id']//tr")

for row in rows:
    row_columns = row.find_element_by_xpaths('//tr')
    for column in columns:
        do_something_with_column_text(column.text)
```

table_rows would end up being a list of all table rows that have a parent table with the id 'table_id'. Then would iterate through each column of each row.